# "Realise a purpose"

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to say the following sentence?

> These people want to **realise their purposes**.

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear to me what

> These people want to realise their purposes. ❌

means. It might mean "these people want to come to understand what their purposes are". It might mean "these people want to make their purposes real (that is accomplish them)". In neither case do I think it a good or clear form of expression. I don't see any grammatical error, but I think it is poor writing.

Comment: I replaced the image with [the cross mark emoji](https://emojipedia.org/cross-mark/) for better readability (if you don't mind)

Comment: Okay, in this case I should write "accomplish purposes" rather than "realise purposes", shouldn't I?

Comment: @inthenickoftime  If you mean "accomplish" then yes. If you means something different, then I'm not sure what that might be.

Comment: Yeap, it's definitely what I meant. In my mother tongue the word "realise" has only one this meaning and therefore I did not take into consideration other possibilities of using it. Thanks for you answer!